# JPA annotation to add and view values from a reference table

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

Say I have this class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PICTURE")
public class Picture{
   private String category1, category2;
}
```

but the database structure looks like this:

```
TABLE PICTURE {
   int category1;
   int category2;
   ...
}

TABLE PICTURE_REF {
   int category;
   String categoryName;
   ...
}
```

How would I use JPA annotations on `Picture` so that any time I request an instance of it, `category1` and `category2` contains the `categoryName` from the PICTURE_REF table instead of the actual integer id stored in the PICTURE table?

I'm also wondering how saves would work because the user would select a category from a dropdown and the corresponding category integer ID would be what's stored in the PICTURE table.

Comment: I suppose this is a bit of a design question as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description , `PICTURE.category1` and `PICTURE.category2` have the many-to-one relationship to the `PICTURE_REF`

The following shows the *bi-directional* mapping between them using annotation:

For table PICTURE:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PICTURE")
public Class Picture{

   @Id
   private Integer id;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name = "category1")
   private PictureRef category1, 

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name = "category2")
   private PictureRef category2;


   //getter and setters 

}
```

For table PICTURE_REF:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PICTURE_REF")
public Class PictureRef{

   @Id
   private Integer id;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category1")
   List <Picture> listOfCat1Picture= new ArrayList<Picture>();  

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category2")
   List <Picture> listOfCat2Picture= new ArrayList<Picture>(); 

   //getter and setters 

}
```

Important Points:

- `@Entity` marks the java class as an hibernate entity. It is mapped to the name of the table specified in the `@Table`
- Use `@ManyToOne` to define the many-to-one relationship

  In the relational database , many-to-one relationship is expressed by using the following foreign key constraint:
  "Many side table" has a FK column which only accepts the PK of the "one side table".

  In your case , these FK columns are  `PICTURE.category1` and `PICTURE.category2`. The name of these FK columns can be explicitly defined  by the `name` attribute of `@JoinColumn`.
- `FetchType.EAGER` makes that `PictureRef` will be eagerly fetched whenever `Picture` is loaded or get
- Depending on your requirement , you can do the `unidirectional` mapping by omitting `@OneToMany` in the `PictureRef`.It will also work .But given `PictureRef` , you cannot access its Picture
- Given a Picture instance , you can get its categoryName and categoryId by

  - picture.getCategory1().getCategoryName()
  - picture.getCategory1().getId()
  - picture.getCategory2().getCategoryName()
  - picture.getCategory2().getId()

Answer (score 2):

**If you can't modify the schema**

You can modify your mapping so Category is an entity instead of just a String.  Then you would have a OneToOne or (more likely) a ManyToOne from Picture to Category for category1 and category2.

**If you CAN modify the schema**
You can use an ElementCollection on Picture to store a List instead of having category1 and category2. This would give you a schema something like

```
TABLE PICTURE {
   long key;
}

TABLE PICTURE_CATEGORY {
    long picture_key;
    String category_name;
}
```

OR you can again map Category to an entity and use a ManyToMany from Picture to Category which would give you a schema like

```
TABLE PICTURE {
   long key;
   ...
}

TABLE PICTURE_CATEGORY {
    long picture_key;
    long category_key;
}

TABLE CATEGORY {
    long key;
    String name;
}
```

As for saving, you will can use a converter in whatever your view technology is that will converter from key to Category, or you can load the Category from the key in your controller and set it in the Picture before you save.  I doubt you'll want saving a Picture to cascade into a Category.

Comment: Hi, I have a similar scenario , that you described above having three tables. How would you map your entity for this kind of a scenario ? For my thing, The CATEGORY table is kind of a lookup table, I mean the application should not insert or update. I used the ManyToMany annotation with JoinTable annotation , it tries to insert as a new record to the Caetgory table which I dont want. Can you help with this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25771892/column-insertable-updateble-dont-go-well-with-spring-jpa